# Parse date java

Tags: java, date, format

How can I parse this date format `Mon May 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)` to this date format `05-14-2010` I mean `mm-dd-yyyy`

it's telling me this error :

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon May 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)"`

**EDIT**

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M-d-yyyy");
newFirstDate = formatter.parse(""+vo.getFirstDate());  //here the error
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the code you've been trying to use.

Comment: What's the return type and value of `vo.getFirstDate()`?

Comment: I have edited my post. vo.getFirstDate() returns a date in the first format :`Mon May 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)`

Comment: If it returns a `java.util.Date` there's no need to `parse()` and all you need is `new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(vo.getFirstDate())`.

Comment: @PhilippReichart `System.out.println(new Date());` prints `Wed May 23 21:33:01 CEST 2012` on my system. It's not the format OP is showing.

Comment: @adil With Marko's observation (thanks!) about the output of `new Date().toString()`, I assume the return type of `vo.getFirstDate()` is `String`, not `java.util.Date`. Is that correct?

Comment: @PhilippReichart That `""+...` is very suspicious, though. Why would he add that if he already had a `String`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code first adapts the string a bit and then goes on to parse it. It respects the timezone, just removes "GMT" because that's how `SimpleDateFormat` likes it.

```
final String date = "Mon May 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)"
  .replaceFirst("GMT", "");
System.out.println(
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(
        new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse(date)));
```

Prints:

```
05-14-2010
```

Bear in mind that the output is also timezone-sensitive. The instant defined by your input string is being interpreted **in my timezone** as belonging to the date that the program printed. If you just need to transform "May 14 2010" into "05-14-2010", that's another story and `SimpleDateFormat` is not well suited for that. The `JodaTime` library would handle that case much more cleanly.

Comment: Thanks, same error : `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon May 14 2012 00:00:00 +0100"`

Comment: @adil I ran this code and didn't get the exception. The code prints as the answer states. This is Java 6, BTW. I see from your message that you obviously didn't run my code, but some version of your own. Since I don't know what exact code you ran to get the exception, there's little I can do about it.

Comment: @adil Now I parsed the exact string you complain about in the comment above: `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("Mon May 14 2012 00:00:00 +0100")));` and it prints `05-14-2012`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test
{
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws ParseException
    {
        // Remove GMT from date string.
        String string = "Mon May 14 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Afr. centrale Ouest)".replace( "GMT" , "" );

        // Parse string to date object.
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat( "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z" ).parse( string );

        // Format date to new format
        System.out.println( new SimpleDateFormat( "MM-dd-yyyy" ).format( date ) );
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
05-13-2010
```

Comment: It's related to the question now, but very brittle.

Comment: Updated again, this time with less brittle.